# Error when executing program Object is not suscriptable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to ake a program but I get this error once I execute it: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

This error appears in line 64 and 95 and I don't understand why. Line 63 seems correct. I cannot figure out why but it is so annoying.

How can I correct it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

class Main:

    db_name = 'materiales.db'
    
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Stock App')

        #create frame
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Add stock')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

        # Name Input
        Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # Quantity Input
        Label(frame, text = 'Quantity: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.quantity = Entry(frame)
        self.quantity.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        # Button Add Stock
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Add Stock', command = self.add_stock).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        #Log Message
        self.message = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        #Button Search Stocks
        ttk.Button(text = 'Search Stocks', command = self.search_stocks).grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20, sticky = W + E) 



    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get()) != 0 and len(self.quantity.get()) !=0
        

    def add_stock(self):
        time = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        hour = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")     
        query = 'SELECT totalstock FROM Stocks WHERE name = ? ORDER BY MovementID DESC LIMIT 1'
        parameters = (self.name.get(),)
        lastrecord = self.run_query(query, parameters)
        total = lastrecord.fetchone()[0]
        total += int(self.quantity.get())
        query = 'SELECT precio FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        parameters = (self.name.get(),)
        precio = self.run_query(query, parameters)
        pricequantity = precio.fetchone()[0] * int(self.quantity.get())
        priceforall = precio.fetchone()[0] * int(total)

        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.name.get(), self.quantity.get(), pricequantity, total, priceforall, time, hour)
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'Stock for {} added succesfully'.format(self.name.get())
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.quantity.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Name and Quantity required'

    def search_stocks(self):
        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Search Stocks'

        #Name Product
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        name = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        name.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        #Log Message
        self.message = Label(self.edit_wind, text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E) 

        Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Update', command = lambda: self.edit_records(name.get())).grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)
               
    def edit_records(self, name):
        query = 'SELECT totalstock FROM Stocks WHERE name = ? ORDER BY MovementID DESC LIMIT 1'
        parameters = (self.name.get(),)
        totalstock = self.run_query(query, parameters)
        totalstock = totalstock.fetchone()[0]
        self.message['text'] = 'Total stock is {}'.format(totalstock.fetchone()[0])
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Main(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

I would be glad if somebody can help me out.
Thanks and Kind regards

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have line numbers, but I can tell you that this line `self.message['text']` is probably wrong as you assign self.message = Label(...) in the constructor (unless Label is a subclass of dict).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have ammended it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stacktrace. Also, explain what you've done to debug this. Clearly, a variable is `None` when you expect it to be something else. Have you tried to figure out why it is `None`?